# How to place a silverlight pie-chart as push pin in bing maps's silverlight plugin

Tags: silverlight, pie-chart, bing-maps

Can anyone put me in the right direction. I am able to get examples from this link http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/ to work but I haven't been able to use the pie chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy. Create your pie chart UIElement and then use the MapLayer.Position and MapLayer.PositionOrigin properties to set the position of the pie chart. Then add the pie chart to the map's children property or a MapLayer.

There is a code sample here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/#MapControlInteractiveSdk.Tutorials.UIElements.TutorialPositionLocation